# fill combobox based on user choice of filename

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

i'm just starting my steps to get deep into wpf mvvm and having hard times little bit to have a good binding to a combobox after getting dynamicly the path to the requested file with database tables in order to fill  combobox.
this is what i accomplish for now:

### ViewModel

```
public class ComboViewModel: ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private TableList tableList1;
    private TableList tableList2;

    public TableList TableList1
    {
        get
        {
            return tableList1;
        }
        set
        {
            if (tableList1 != value)
            {
                tableList1 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("TableList1");
            }
        }
    }
    public TableList TableList2
    {
        get 
        {
            return tableList2; 
        }
        set
        {
            if (tableList2 != value)
            {
                tableList2 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("TableList2");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

### MODEL

```
public class TableList
{
    public List<string> TBL = null; 
    public TableList()
    {

    }
    public List<string> TablesList(string mdbDir)
    {
        DbConnection connection;
        DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.OleDb");
        DataTable userTables = null;
        List<string> mdbTblList = new List<string>();
        connection = factory.CreateConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + mdbDir;
        string[] restrictions = new string[4];
        restrictions[3] = "Table";
        try
        {
            connection.Open();

            userTables = connection.GetSchema("Tables", restrictions);

            for (int i = 0; i < userTables.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                mdbTblList.Add(userTables.Rows[i][2].ToString());
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        return mdbTblList;
    }
```

### XAML

```html
<ComboBox Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,40,0,130" DataContext="{Binding ComboViewModel}"  SelectedItem="{Binding ListTable1}"> </ComboBox>
```

Comment: Just a comment to your model-class: A model does not contain any logic. The only exception for this rule is the validation.

Answer (score 1):

Let's concentrate on the view: In order to show items bind `ComboBox.ItemsSource` to the collection of objects (db table names I suppose). The collection should be located in the combobox' DataContext (ComboViewModel). For the `SelectedItem` binding in your combobox you need a property ListTable1 (why not rename to SelectedTable?) of the same type as the generic type of the collection in ComboViewModel.

---

EDIT

```
public class ComboViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
   private List<string> tables;
   public List<string> Tables {
      get { return tables; }
      set {
         tables = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("Tables");
      }
   }

   private string selectedTable;
   public string SelectedTable {
      get { return selectedTable; }
      set {
            selectedTable = value;
            // react to user selection
        }
   }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
      if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
         this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }
}

public class FileDialogViewModel {
    ComboViewModel ComboVM {
        get { /* return ComboViewModel instance */ }
    }

    void UpdateTables(string mdbDir) {
        ComboVM.Tables = TablesList(mdbDir);
    }
}
```

Xaml

```
<!-- DataContext has to be the ComboViewModel instance -->
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Tables}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTable}" />
```

Comment: Hi, 2 tables lists its case specific for my program, my program is basically based on the MDB file suppose to get list of tables but i'm searching how to trigger the comboviewmodel and fill combo based on the filedialogviewmodel, what should be changed in the view model to be able to trigger it + to fill combo additionally how can i pass the file path to the Tableslist function

Comment: to make it short, i need the combobox to be filled after getting file path

Comment: Then you'll need something like this:
in ComboViewModel a public property `List<string> Tables` with its setter calling `OnPropertyChanged`;
in ComboBox-Tag a binding `ItemsSource={Binding Tables}` (remove the current SelectedItem binding, that doesn't make sense);
in FileDialogViewModel a reference to your `ComboViewModel` instance;
After the user's choice in FileDialogViewModel set `ComboViewModel.Tables` to the list generated by your `TablesList` method.

Comment: thank you for the explenation do you have any code example maybe?

Comment: thank you for the answer,its very helpfull, is it in the standards of mvvm?can it be done in delegate way?

Comment: The communication between view and viewmodel is standard in mvvm. The only part that is not strictly mvvm is the `TablesList` call; I would rather put this into your model.

Comment: i dont understand how can i run the function TablesList when its inside the class TableList(model).

Comment: the only way possible as i see is by instantiate tablelist class

Comment: i tried to run it and from some reason first of all the tablelist list is been built and then the comboviewmodel is instantiated and the object is null

Comment: Normally the viewmodel has an instance of the model, so it shouldn't be a problem to call a model method.

Comment: from some reason the table object is keeping null, think something is still missing. i tried to do this public class FileDialogViewModel {
    ComboViewModel ComboVM {
        get { new ComboViewModel()}
    } void UpdateTables(string mdbDir) {
        ComboVM.Tables = (new TableList()).TablesList(mdbDir);
    }

Comment: table object i mean ComboVM.Tables, i think additionaly that something is wrong OnPropertyChanged("Tables") becaouse , propertychanged object is staying null, maybe if there would be a way to instantiate it so it might work

Comment: i think there must me some misundestanding becaouse comboviewmodel is seperated from filedialogviewmodel and as i see the code above comboviewmodel is in composition under filedialogviewmodel

Comment: this part is used to keep both viewmodels, maybe something need to be changed here :    class MainViewModel
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            FileDialogViewModel = new FileDialogViewModel { };
            ComboViewModel = new ComboViewModel { };
        }

        public ComboViewModel ComboViewModel
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public FileDialogViewModel FileDialogViewModel
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

my solution was to make property public ComboViewModel ComboViewModel  static and to send the tablelist on activeting filedialogviewmodel